# Solution of simultaneous equations using properties of symmetric polynomials

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

> Solve the following system of equations.
>
> $$ x + y + z = 5 $$ 
>   $$ \frac{1}{xy}+\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{zx} = 5 $$ 
>   $$ x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 53 $$

How would I use properties of symmetric polynomials (e) to solve this?

Comment: You should really show an attempt at a solution if you're going to ask this many homework questions in a day. If you're prepping for the GRE, I apologize.

Comment: use identity $(x+y+z)^3$

Answer (score 4):

.From $\frac{1}{yz} + \frac{1}{xz} + \frac{1}{xy} = 5$, we get:
$$
\frac{x+y+z}{zyx} = 5 \implies zyx = 1
$$

Now, $$
x^3+y^3+z^3 - 3xyz= (x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2 - xy-yz-zx) \\= (x+y+z)((x+y+z)^2-3(xy+yz+zx))
$$
 Solving using values, this gives $xy+yz+zx = 5$.

Now, note that:
$$
(t-x)(t-y)(t-z) = t^3 - (xy+yz+zx)t^2 + (x+y+z)t - xyz \\= t^3 - 5t^2 + 5t-1 
$$
Hence, if we are able to find the roots of this equation, we can find the values of $x,y,z$.

By inspection, $t=1$ works, hence $t-1$ ia a factor.

After the division ,we are left with $t^2-4t+1$, which gives $t = 2 \pm \sqrt{3}$.

Thus, $x=1, y,z = 2 \pm \sqrt{3}$, and since  the equation is symmetric, any two of these can be switched.